# strange network activity - tcpkill not working, port 4001

Tags: networking, tcp, port, firewall, trojan

I am on a VPS, with tcpdump I noticied some traffic from and to port 4001 on my machine.
I tried `lsof -i :4001` which gives nothing
I tried `tcpkill port 4001`, which gives "`tcpkill: write: Operation not permitted`"

I also have this port blocked with firewall (input and output)

Would you have any idea what is this traffic, why I cannot see the process and why I cannot stop it?

tcpdump -n -X gives something like this:

```
11:29:59.434409 IP foreignIP.4018 > myIP.4001: Flags [.], ack 1, win 501, length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0028 766e 4000 3406 3df2 334f e45d  E..(vn@.4.=.3O.]
    0x0010:  8b63 ef5f 0fb2 0fa1 9dd6 1baf 7215 425c  .c._........r.B\
    0x0020:  5010 01f5 8e25 0000                      P....%..
11:29:59.454867 IP myIP.4001 > foreignIP.4004: Flags [.], ack 1, win 6141, length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0028 ae3d 4000 7f06 bb22 8b63 ef5f  E..(.=@....".c._
    0x0010:  334f e45d 0fa1 0fa4 4a40 3666 3405 791f  3O.]....J@6f4.y.
    0x0020:  5010 17fd b857 0000
```

Comment: Did you try with `sudo`? https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=4001 lists some options but that might mean nothing. You can also try to capture process information - that's OS dependent but e.g. on MacOS it's possible with `tcpdump -k`.

Comment: yes I am already connected as root, machine is Debian 10, tcpdump -k not working. How would I know it is is trojan optixpro?

Comment: `netstat -putna | grep 4001` to find listening process?

Comment: this gives nothing just like lsof